# BizTalk Orchestration BTS object to class library

Tags: c#, biztalk, class-library, biztalk-orchestrations

I'm trying to create a Log sampel c# class and wondering if it posible to pass BTS object in orchestration to a class?

BTS have BTS.messagetype, bts.messageID and much more that i would like to use.

If yes any idea how i can achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried?   It is fairly simply to call an external C# class and pass it those things.  You will have to pass them as individual items rather than an Object, because it isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

by sending XLANGMessage in as parameter to my function. i can get all those property